# Creating Content Grouping on Android SDK

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am using the Android SDK to send data to Google Analytics. In this project I cannot use Firebase nor GTM. I should send hits directly to GA. I have already implemented everything, events included. But I cannot create Content Groupings. I think that the follow code is deprecated, isn't it?

*mTracker tracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker("UA-XXXXXXXX-X");
mTracker.set(contentGroup(1), "Level");*

Which is the **correct implementation for creating Content Grouping** with the **Android SDK** without using other platforms (I mean sending everything **directly to GA**)?

Thanks a lot.